# How to know if apple pay/google pay or smart card communicate with NFC reader

Tags: nfc, emv

There is tag PAR(9f24) in documentation, but i don't see him when read  application data from google pay. I just need to read pan. Is it possible detect who communicate with nfc reader?

Answer (score -1):

For eg. Visa card, 9F24 is a part of DGI 0104, so if present you should be getting it in your READ RECORD 1, 4. Similarly you can check for other payment schemes.

If it is a wallet, it is a token(surrogate pan) you will receive instead of actual PAN. For a terminal it is as good as a pan that it can't differentiate whether it is a real pan or surrogate. PAN/Token you should be receiving in READ RECORD, Tag 57.

What do you mean by 'detect who communicate with nfc reader' ?